# Wait for result of async function in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I have a question related to my code:

```
func isNotificationsEnabled()->Bool{
    var isNotificationEnabled = false
    center.getNotificationSettings() { (settings) in
        switch settings.soundSetting{
        case .enabled:
            isNotificationEnabled = true
           break
        case .disabled:
             isNotificationEnabled = false
             break

        case .notSupported:
            isNotificationEnabled = false
             break
        }
    }

     return isNotificationEnabled
}
```

This function return result before `center.getNotificationSettings()` returns results. Is there any way to wait for result of `center.getNotificationSettings()` and sync this function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning data from async call in Swift function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function)

Comment: Don't ask, tell! Use an asynchronous completion handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is called Completion block in iOS,
Try this,

```
func isNotificationsEnabled(completion:@escaping (Bool)->Swift.Void){
        var isNotificationEnabled = false
        center.getNotificationSettings() { (settings) in
            switch settings.soundSetting{
            case .enabled:
                isNotificationEnabled = true
                completion(isNotificationEnabled)
                break
            case .disabled:
                isNotificationEnabled = false
                completion(isNotificationEnabled)
                break

            case .notSupported:
                isNotificationEnabled = false
                completion(isNotificationEnabled)
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage,

```
isNotificationsEnabled { (isNotificationEnabled) in
    debugPrint(isNotificationEnabled)           
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an example using a completion block, it's reduced but has the same functionality as your code:

```
func isNotificationsEnabled(completion:@escaping (Bool)->() ) {
    center.getNotificationSettings() { (settings) in
        switch settings.soundSetting {
        case .enabled:
            completion(true)
            
        default:
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}
```

which can be still more reduced to the essential:

```
func isNotificationsEnabled(completion:@escaping (Bool)->() ) {
    center.getNotificationSettings() { (settings) in
        completion (settings.soundSetting == .enabled)
    }
}
```

Since only the `.enabled` case returns `true` use `default` to return `false` in all other cases. By the way: In Swift `break` statements are not needed.

And call it:

```
isNotificationsEnabled { success in
    if success {
        print("is enabled")
    } else {
        print("is disabled")
    }
}
```

In **Swift 5.5** and higher you can take advantage of `async/await`

```
func isNotificationsEnabled() async -> Bool {
    let settings = await center.notificationSettings()
    switch settings.soundSetting {
        case .enabled:
            return true
        case .disabled, .notSupported:
            return false    
    }
}
```

Comment: The Swift 5.5 example does not seem to be correct. I keep getting a `Missing argument for parameter 'completionHandler' in call` error

Comment: Please note the difference between `getNotificationSettings()` with completion handler and `notificationSettings()` without. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649524-getnotificationsettings).

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you can probably simplify this even further:

```
func isNotificationsEnabled(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    center.getNotificationSettings { settings in
        completionHandler(settings.soundSetting == .enabled)
    }
}
```

And as others pointed out, it then is invoked as:

```
isNotificationsEnabled { enabled in
    if enabled {
        print("is enabled")
    } else {
        print("is not enabled")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a completion handler!

```
func isNotificationsEnabled(completion: (Bool) -> ())->Bool{
    var isNotificationEnabled = false
    center.getNotificationSettings() { (settings) in
        switch settings.soundSetting{
        case .enabled:
            isNotificationEnabled = true
           break
        case .disabled:
             isNotificationEnabled = false
             break

        case .notSupported:
            isNotificationEnabled = false
             break
        }
    }

     return isNotificationEnabled
     completion(isNotificationEnabled)
}
```

And then call it

```
isNotificationEnabled() { isNotificationsEnabled in
   print(isNotificationsEnabled)
}
```

Comment: No, you are calling `completion` _after_ your `return` statement (i.e., you'll never get there). You should (a) change the method definition to no longer return anything (given that you now have the completion handler); and (b) remove the `return` statement.